# Не учитывается регистр слов во временной шкале вопроса

Tags: поддержка, временная-шкала

Во временной шкале вопроса, поднятого Духом, например [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1375/timeline), присутствует текст:

> поднят духом сообщества

> [image: поднят духом сообщества]

При этом [соответствующая строка](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/83658777?key=f351b69ecf85717c37709482939efc37) в Transifex содержит заглавные буквы:

> Поднят Духом сообщества

Такое ощущение, что регистр игнорируется где-то по коду сайта при формировании страницы временной шкалы. Для чего это нужно - дополнительно искажать возможность перевода?

Оригинальная строка на enSO тоже [выводится в нижнем регистре](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/261531/timeline), хотя в Transifex содержит и заглавные буквы:

> Bumped by Community user